# java "シンボルを見つけられません"のエラーが発生する

Tags: java

java初心者です。ある参考書にて下記のサンプルコードを入力すると、『java;13(14も同様); エラー:シンボルを見つけられません　emy1.setLife(10); 』と表示されます。
　Enemyクラスを呼び出すためのimport文がないからでしょうか？（サンプルコードには記述されていなかったため、理由がわかりません）
　対処法をご教授いただける方、よろしくお願いします。

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
 
  Enemy emy1;
  Enemy emy2;
  
  emy1 = new Enemy(); //インスタンス生成
  emy2 = new Enemy(); //インスタンス生成
  
  emy1.addEnemy();  //インスタンスからクラスメソッド呼び出し
  emy2.addEnemy();  //インスタンスからクラスメソッド呼び出し
  
  emy1.setLife(10); //インスタンスメソッド呼び出し
  emy2.setLife(20); //インスタンスメソッド呼び出し
  
  System.out.println("敵機総数 : " + Enemy.getSum());
  System.out.println("敵機1ライフポイント : " + emy1.getLife());
  System.out.println("敵機2ライフポイント : " + emy2.getLife());
  }
 }

class Enemy{
   static int sum = 0;
   int life;
   
   static void addEnemy(){
    sum++;
    }
    
   static int getSum(){
     return sum;
     }
    
     void setlife(int life){
      this.life = life;
      }
    
     int getLife(){
       return life;
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
  emy1.setLife(10); //インスタンスメソッド呼び出し
```

```java
     void setlife(int life){
```

`L` と `l` が違っています。メソッド名は大文字小文字を区別します。